# How to forward email to my Gmail account with GoDaddy?

Tags: email, godaddy

I've just got a new domain with GoDaddy. I want to forward email to various addresses to different Gmail addresses.

I can't find this option in the GoDaddy control panel. The clostest thing I can see is a link to buy an email forwarding package. Do they actually charge extra to set up email forwarding!?

Are there any ways to forward it for free?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Apps is quite user friendly and gives you 50 email accounts to use plus other cool stuff.  To get the emails to go to Google Apps you will need to set the MX records on the GoDaddy control panel.

Once you created an email account with Google Apps you can forward that email to any other email you like.

Comment: Unfortunately, Google Apps no longer offers a free tier, their plans are now pay-only.

Answer (score 3):

What you bought is only a domain in the DNS servers. It *does not come* with email, nor with any other services.

You will need to set up an email service for your domain. If you are only interested in forwarding, the easiest choice would be [Google Apps](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html) (which gives you a fully working Gmail-like service too).

Answer (score 2):

You can get your email sent to an address like `yourname@yourdomainname.com` if you use Google Apps, even if you only bought the standard package when you got your domain name through GoDaddy.

Get a Google Apps account and then prove the domain name is yours by following the instructions when you set up Google Apps.

Finally use these [instructions](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=33353) to setup the email in GoDaddy - you'll have to add a CNAME entry and some MX entries.